# How can I make calculations in relations model class and receive clear data

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relation

I have this object and as you can see I sort by different variables

```
$banks = Bank::with('credits')->with('deposits')->with('bank_assets')->with('atms')->get()->sortByDesc($sort);
```

So I have relations in my model for example bank_assets (credits and deposits working clearly and i can sort by deposit or by credit)
But bank_assets! No
In this case I need to sort by actives which I need to calculate.
Because Actives this is a summ of different ammounts from this table http://prntscr.com/ij3idg
And In my model relation I get only the object not a summ of this amounts
As you can see

```
//Bank Model
    public function bank_assets()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\BankRating')->where('type','assets');
    }
```

But I need to sort by actives which is a summ of different amounts
Please Help me and Explaine How I can sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this would sort according to `$sort` parameter and `ammount` property on `bank_assets` relation:

```
$banks = Bank::with([
    'credits',
    'deposits',
    'bank_assets'
    'atms',
])->get()->sortByDesc(function($bank) use ($sort) {
    if($sort == 'actives') {
        return $bank->bank_assets->sum('ammount');
    }
    return $bank->$sort;
});
```

hope this works. ;)

Comment: And if I dont know which ellement I need to summ and the quantaty of them Just condition -> all ammounts which connected with this bank_id and has type assets

Comment: what do you mean by `all ammouts`

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean field1+field in my case what is field

Comment: If I type such $banks = Bank::with([
            'credits',
            'deposits',
            'bank_assets' => function ($query) {
                $query->selectRaw('*, amount as actives')
                    ->orderBy('actives', 'desc');
            },
            'atms',
        ])->get()->sortByDesc($sort);

Comment: `field1` can be the names of the columns on basis of whose sum, you are going to sort. for example you want to sort according to the sum of `amount` and `tax` columns then your fields you should use `selectRaw('*, amount+tax as actives')`.
And for the error that you get, make sure you have `bank_assets` method on your `Bank` Model.

Comment: No I want just to sort by ammount field, Please Help me to make query

Comment: I am trying to make something like this

Comment: `switch($sort){
        case "actives" :
        $banks = Bank::with('credits')->with('deposits')->with('bank_assets')->with('atms')->get();
        foreach ($banks as $bank){
            foreach ($bank->bank_assets as $asset){
                $bank->actives=$bank->actives+$asset->amount;
            }
        }
            usort($banks,[$this,'mySort']);
        default:
        $banks = Bank::with('credits')->with('deposits')->with('bank_assets')->with('atms')->get()->sortByDesc($sort);
    }` But here I can not use usort because of the object not array

Comment: And how I can use $sort variable which coming from the GET parametr?

Comment: I need something like this `$banks = Bank::with([
            'credits',
            'deposits',
            'bank_assets',
            'atms',
        ])->get()->sortByDesc($sort,(function($bank) {
            if($sort==actives){
            return $bank->bank_assets->amount;
            }
        })); `But it is not correct

Comment: what is that GET parameter for? Do you  want sort acccording to parameter or `ammount`? Please explain more in your question. Chck my answer again.

Comment: Or Something Like This http://prntscr.com/ij4ffm But it didnt sort by actives (( http://prntscr.com/ij4h5b

Comment: Answer Updated!

Comment: credits and deposits should be working fine if these properties exist on `bank` model and passed into $sort as GET parameter.

Comment: Ah! Fixed that.

Comment: You should slect this answer if it solved your problem.